# suspicious request to real IP of my server

Tags: server, cloudflare

Im using cloudflare and 100% sure my real server IP address is not leaked . I checked it out with various tools . the real IP address isn't register in DNS history at all but when I check the server logs , saw a lot of  suspicious requests that doesn't come from cloudflare hit my server. How could this happen ?

Comment: It's fairly trivial to scan over every possible address on common ports (or even over ports too). I had a server up on my computer for kicks for a bit, but stopped because people scanning in China kept popping up in the logs and I got rightfully paranoid.

Comment: @Carcigenicate yes you are right ! ... actually I guessed that but now I got confident